# How to retrieve data from different columns in different tables and combine them into one report

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have two tables:

**Admission**

StudentID | Subject

**PersonalDetails**

StudentID | FirstName | LastName | ContactNumber | Email

My question is, how do I retrieve all of the student ID's from the admission's table where they have a certain subject next to them, and then retrieve the details of this student from the Personal Details Table, compiling all of this into one report.

I'm using a MS Access Database, and VB.Net! If you can help it would be great, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Build a query. Use the MS Access query design wizard.

Comment: I want to produce the report using VB, to display to the user once they have selected the subject from a combo box and clicked a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you need will be along the lines of this I'd guess. **Edit** If you want to report on a selected subject at a time, then adding a where clause:

```
select pd.*
from Admission a
inner join PersonalDetails pd on a.StudentId = pd.StudentId
where a.Subject = @subject
order by pd.LastName, pd.FirstName
```

Although, if you're just starting out with DB querying, admittedly this sql might not be particularly useful for you. Maybe check out some tutorials on building queries in MS Access like [this one](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quick-tutorial-queries-microsoft-access-2007/), or [this MS one](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/queries-i-get-answers-with-queries-RZ001077757.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to create a query in MSAccess. You're going to have to put a condition on the join. After that, bind your VB.NET application to the query.

Comment: Okay that's great, but what do you mean by a condition on the join?